# C# Report Renderer for SRSS 2008 R2 - Missing Parameter

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008

I'm using C# to render a report from SRSS 2008 R2
The report has parameters and for a long time I have had no problem rendering the output. However today it has decided its not going to work!

Here is the error

`ReportServerException: This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter 'CustomFieldId'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value. (rsReportParameterValueNotSet): Stack:    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e)`

Here is the code:

```
ReportViewer rv = new ReportViewer();
rv.ShowCredentialPrompts = true;
rv.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
rv.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ReportsClient.ReportServerUrl);
rv.ServerReport.ReportPath = string.Format("/Reports/{0}", item.Name);
rv.ServerReport.SetParameters(thisLoopParams.ToArray());
rv.ServerReport.Timeout = -1;
rv.ServerReport.Refresh();

// render the report
string mimeType = string.Empty;
string extention = string.Empty;
string encoding = string.Empty;
string[] streamIds;
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] warnings = null;

byte[] result = rv.ServerReport.Render(outputFormat, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extention, out streamIds, out warnings);
```

If I inspect `thisLoopParams` I can clearly see the 'CustomFieldId' `ReportParameter` and it definitely has a value, yet the error still appears.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try opening the rdl and add a default value for that parameter.

Comment: done. still getting the same error sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.
I took a look at `ReportParameterInfoCollection paramInfo = rv.ServerReport.GetParameters();` and found some of the parameters were 'Not Valid'. I know why but i was a bit thrown out by the original error of 'Not Provided'. I'm guessing this is because the valids i proided we just discounted

Thanks

Comment: I used this method to explore the parameters that I provided; in my case the GUID parameter I submitted was all uppercase but the valid value was the lower case equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue when i pass value of 'XYZ' field but it says

> This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report
>   parameter

when i see the value of 'XYZ' it has extra space  in starting when i  removed this space it surprisingly starts working.I don't know the reason but it works.Hope it may help you.