# SSRS and powershell: Parameter not accepted

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I use Powershell to run several reports on Microsoft SQL Report Services and to save the results to a Word doc. I have a script with functions that handle communications with the Report Server:

```
## File "qrap-functions.ps1"
function GetRSConnection($server, $instance)
{
    $User = "xxxx"
    $PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "yyyy" -AsPlainText -Force
    $c = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord

    $reportServerURI = "http://" + $server + "/" + $instance + "/ReportExecution2005.asmx?WSDL"

    $RS = New-WebServiceProxy -Class 'RS' -NameSpace 'RS' -Uri $reportServerURI -Credential $c
    $RS.Url = $reportServerURI
    return $RS
}
function GetReport($RS, $reportPath)
{
    $reportPath = "/" + $reportPath
    #$reportPath
    $Report = $RS.GetType().GetMethod("LoadReport").Invoke($RS, @($reportPath, $null))      
    $parameters = @()
    $RS.SetExecutionParameters($parameters, "nl-nl") > $null
    return $report
}
function AddParameter($params, $name, $val)
{
    $par = New-Object RS.ParameterValue
    $par.Name = $name
    $par.Value = $val
    $params += $par
    return ,$params
}
function GetReportInFormat($RS, $report, $params, $format, $saveas)
{
    $deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><NoHeader>True</NoHeader></DeviceInfo>"
    $extension = ""
    $mimeType = ""
    $encoding = ""
    $warnings = $null
    $streamIDs = $null

    $RS.SetExecutionParameters($params, "nl-nl") > $null

    $RenderOutput = $RS.Render($format,
        $deviceInfo,
        [ref] $extension,
        [ref] $mimeType,
        [ref] $encoding,
        [ref] $warnings,
        [ref] $streamIDs
    )
    $Stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($saveas), Create, Write
    $Stream.Write($RenderOutput, 0, $RenderOutput.Length)
    $Stream.Close()
}
```

Then, I have a script that executes a report containing the financial quarterly data. This script runs fine:

```
## File "qrap-financieel.ps1"
. "./qrap-functions.ps1"

$saveas = "e:\test\financieel.doc"
$RS = GetRSConnection -server "MSZRDWH" -instance "reportserver_acc"
$report = GetReport -RS $RS -reportPath "kwartaalrapportage/kwartaalrapportage financieel"
$params = @()   
$kwartaal = "[Periode Maand].[Jaar Kwartaal].&[2015-2]"
$kptc = "[Kostenplaats].[Team code].&[2003]"

$params = AddParameter -params $params -name "PeriodeMaandJaarKwartaal" -val $kwartaal
$params = AddParameter -params $params -name "KostenplaatsTeamcode" -val $kptc

GetReportInformat -RS $RS -report $report -params $params -format "WORD" -saveas $saveas
```

The values for `$kwartaal` and `$kptc` are hard-coded here, but are parameters in the actual version of this script. Besides the financial quarterly, we have three other quarterly reports that need to be output by this script.
Two of these run fine, in the fourth I can't seem to get one of the parameters right. The script for that one is:

```
## File "qrap-zorglog.ps1"
. "./qrap-functions.ps1"
$RS = GetRSConnection -server "MSZRDWH" -instance "reportserver_acc"
$report = GetReport -RS $RS -reportPath "kwartaalrapportage/kwartaalrapportage zorglogistiek"

$s = "Urologie"
$saveas = "e:\test\ZL Urologie.doc"
$params = @()   
$kwartaal = "[Periode Maand].[Jaar Kwartaal].&[2015-2]" 

$params = AddParameter -params $params -name "HoofdspecialismeSpecialismeOms"                       -val "[Hoofdspecialisme].[Specialisme Oms].&[$s]"
$params = AddParameter -params $params -name "PeriodeMaandJaarKwartaal"                             -val $kwartaal
$params = AddParameter -params $params -name "WachttijdenSpecialismeSpecialisme"                    -val "[Wachttijden Specialisme].[Specialisme].&[$s]"
$params = AddParameter -params $params -name "SpecialisatieGroeperingSpecialisatieGroeperingOms"    -val "[Specialistie Groepering].[Specialistie Groepering Oms].&[$s]"    
$params = AddParameter -params $params -name "AanvragendSpecialismeSpecialismeOms"                  -val "[AanvragendSpecialisme].[Specialisme Oms].&[$s]"

GetReportInformat -RS $RS -report $report -params $params -format "WORD" -saveas $saveas
```

When I execute this script, I get this error:

```
Exception calling "Render" with "7" argument(s): "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: This report requires a 
default or user-defined value for the report parameter 'HoofdspecialismeSpecialismeOms'. To run or subscribe to this 
report, you must provide a parameter value. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportParameterValueNot
SetException: This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter 
'HoofdspecialismeSpecialismeOms'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value.
```

I clearly DO supply a value for 'HoofdspecialismeSpecialismeOms'; I've previously noticed that this error also is thrown when the parameter is not in the expected format. This format, since the 
report filter is based on a hierarchy in an SSAS cube, looks like this: `[hierarchy].[sub-level].&[member]`. I've ensured that `[Hoofdspecialisme].[Specialisme Oms].&[$s]` is the correct format by
looking it up in the query that populates the prompt in SSRS. The report does display data when run through SSRS - and taking a parameter from the prompt.

I did notice that this parameter allows multiple selection. However, I don't believe this leads to the error because that is also true for `AanvragendSpecialismeSpecialismeOms`.

Any idea why this one parameter fails to be fed into the report when calling `GetReportInformat`?

Comment: I haven't worked much with Powershell but have you tried without the extra spaces between the parameters? It IS space delimited.

Comment: @HannoverFist I've just tried to run the script without the additional spaces and tabs between the `-name` and `-val` parameters, but no luck. I still get the same error. Moving `HoofdspecialismeSpecialismeOms` around in the order of parameters changes nothing either.

Comment: @Matt You're right about `$q`. In my script, that's a parameter. Write-Host tells me this gets resolved exactly as I want it to. I've edited the question to fix this value. The script does have a definition for `$s`, though, this is "Urologie".

Comment: If you change the parameter order does the error still show for that entry?

Comment: @Matt Yes, changing the order has no effect on the error message. I know there can be cross-dependencies between paratemers, but that does not apply here.

Comment: Right before the call to `$RS.Render()`, what happens if you call `$RS.GetParameters()` and inspect?  (based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14751974/1001100))

Comment: @JamesQMurphy The answer linked deals with C#, and I'm guessing with a higher version of SSRS. I'm running 2012, and I can't seem to get `GetParameters()` to work. I've tried several different ways; `GetExcecutionParameters`, `GetExecutionOptions`, using `$RS.nnn()` or `$RS.GetType().Invoke()`; no luck on a `GetPatameter` kind of method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured it out: The failing prompt had a multi-select enabled. And when filling in a multi-select, SSRS expects a list of values. When only given one string, the string is ignored and the parameter is assumed blank.

To feed it a list, we must do:

```
$multival = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$multival.Add("[Hoofdspecialisme].[Specialisme Oms].&[$s]")
[snip]
$params = AddParameter -params $params -name "HoofdspecialismeSpecialismeOms" -val $multival
```

Found the answer thanks to this question:
[How to pass multiple value parameter to reporting services report via powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938389/how-to-pass-multiple-value-parameter-to-reporting-services-report-via-powershell)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
function AddParameter($params, $name, $val)
{
    $par = New-Object RS.ParameterValue
    $par.Name = $name
    $par.Value = $val
    $params += $par
    return ,$params
    #      ^Removing this comma?
}
```

As well as declaring the data types explicitly for your parameters?

```
function AddParameter([Array]$params, [String]$name, [String]$val)
{
    $par = New-Object RS.ParameterValue
    $par.Name = $name
    $par.Value = $val
    $params += $par
    return ,$params
}
```

Also, with so many user-defined helper functions calling imported types that call methods and set properties to a report we can't see, it can get a little difficult to help troubleshoot in-depth for this specific report you're getting an error on. It looks like you've tried moving the line around in the order which sounds to me like you might have an issue with how that specific report parses the values you input through `RS.ParameterValue` so maybe take a look at if it accepts the string you set in `-val` for your `AddParameter` user defined function.

## Edit:

From https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e38b4a34-c780-43bb-8321-15f96d0938a9/exception-calling-render-systemwebservicesprotocolssoapexception-one-or-more-data-source?forum=sqlreportingservices

> This error is generated when you are attempting to run a report in which one or more of the data sources are set to "prompt" credentials.  This means we do not use your Windows credentials automatically, but rather you need to supply a different set of credentials which are used only for the data source.

Sounds like you might need to put aside the script and check if the report is different.

Comment: The comma in `AddParameters` is very neccessary. Without it, the list of parameters is converted to its first element only and on a second pass the `+=`operator fails because it is not valid for an `RS.Parameter` object. Also, the data source for the query using (and filling) the `HoofdspecialismeSpecialismeOms` is configured the same as other sources used on both this report and others in the batch. Credentials are supplied to the Report Server in the `GetRSConnection` function.